# Not able to use scanner class

Tags: java.util.scanner

I created a class in java, but not getting how to take a value for the variables from the user as i find an error while importing util package.

code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Box{
    int width;
    int height;
    int breadth;
    int volume(){
        int volume=width*height*breadth;
        return volume;
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Box b1=new Box();
        Box b2=new Box();
        b1.width=sc.nextInt();
        b1.height=sc.nextInt();
        b1.breadth=sc.nextInt();
        b2.width=sc.nextInt();
        b2.height=sc.nextInt();
        b2.breadth=sc.nextInt();
        int b1volume=b1.volume();
        int b2volume=b2.volume();
        System.out.println(b1volume);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(b2volume);
        
    }
}
```

I expect Error less output while using util package

Comment: When you encountered an error, why you don't put it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a scanner object and pass system input to it and then you'll be able to use it.

```
var sc = new Scanner(System.in);
...
```